# Error al ejecutar php artisan serve en ubuntu 20.10

Tags: laravel

Buenas quisiera saber si pueden ayudarme ya estuve googleando y aparentemente tenían la solución pero a mi no me funcionó, al ejecutar:

php artisan serve

me da el siguiente error:

PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/uno/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/uno/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/uno/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/uno/artisan on line 18

este es uno de los enlaces donde encontré una solución propuesta, pero a mi no me funciona.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209349/requirevendor-autoload-php-failed-to-open-stream

PD. tengo instalado composer de forma global cree proyectos de estas formas:
laravel new proyecto
y
composer create-project laravel/laravel proyecto para ver si al haberlo creado de la primera forma era el inconveniente pero no.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: y qué pasa si te mueves al directorio `/opt/lampp/htdocs/uno/` y pones `composer install`?

Comment: si instala vendor, pero habría que hacerlo en cada proyecto y creo que no debería ser así.

Comment: Bueno, se supone que `composer create-project` conlleva `composer install`, y `composer install` conlleva `composer dump-autoload`, pero sólo aspiraba a ayudarte a salir del paso, claramente no es la solución definitiva